# GO - subroutine behaviour in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, concurrency, go, behavior, subroutine

I'm having some doubts on my understanding of the behaviour of a go subroutine in a for loop.

From what I understand, when we have a for loop:

```
for key := range Map {
   go subroutine(Map[key])
}
```

Where Map has, let's say 3 (key,Value) pairs.

So my understanding is that the *subroutine()* function will run concurrently using all the *Map[Key]* values ie subroutine(Map[**key1**]),subroutine(Map[**key2**]) and subroutine(Map[**key3**]) will all run concurrently ?

Is my understanding of concurrent subroutines in a for loop correct?

Thanks!

Comment: What else than a yes/no answer are you looking for ? (The answer though, is yes).

Comment: I just wanted a confirmation or a correction if my understanding was off. Thank you!

Comment: yes and if nothing is waiting for the subroutines to finish your program can/will exit before the subroutines complete

Comment: If maxprocs is 1 you may have some issues. http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please remember that you will still need the main goroutine alive for these to finish before the program ends. You can use something like sync.WaitGroup:

```
wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
for key := range Map {
  wg.Add(1)
  go func() {
    subroutine(Map[key])
    wg.Done()
  }
}
wg.Wait()
```

Or if you have something like a server loop going on in the main routine you may not need that at all since your program won't finish until a relevant signal is externally sent to it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think "defer wg.Done()" should be used inside the anonymous function otherwise it is ignored if the subroutine throws an error